# `find-grep` (aka `grep-find`) not finding a line when in an upper directory

Tags: grep

[Top-posting an update] Results of deeper inquiry, after filing a bug report. It appears that the failure is related to a recent update to the cygwin environment. Where previously the single-quoted parameter `'*.log`' to the -name option to find was passed to find as a single-quoted `'*.log`', the current behaviour has that `'*.log`' expanded to a list of files if there are .log files in the directory in which the find-grep is started.

Changing the invocation to

```
find . -type f -name \\*.log -exec grep -nHE 'ERROR:' {} \;
```

causes the literal `*.log` to be passed to find as desired. More research will be needed to find exactly where the name expansion is happening, but for now this works.

**** end of top-posted update ***

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw) with a cygwin environment installed at C:/cygwin64 on a Windows 7 machine.

`M-x find-grep` (aka `grep-find`), then:

```
find . -type f -name '*-2017-12-12_09.22.57.log' -exec grep -nHE 'ERROR:' {} \;
```

finds a number of ERROR: lines in various `.log` files at various depths in the directory hierarchy where I am working.

One particular file with an 'ERROR:'

```
./PFF/PFF/PFF.bat-2017-12-12_09.22.57.log
```

is not found unless I change down a directory level, starting in `./PFF`, or unless the parent directory name is [at least] one character longer or shorter (but see below.) e.g. the ERROR: line is found in

```
./PFF/PFFm/PFF.bat-2017-12-12_09.22.57.log
```

or in

```
./PFF/PFF-/PFF.bat-2017-12-12_09.22.57.log
```

but never in

```
./PFF/PFF/PFF.bat-2017-12-12_09.22.57.log
```

whether the original `./PFF/PFF` directory is renamed or copied to a [longer-named] parent (when copied, I have both `./PFF/PFF` and `./PFF/PFFx` directories.)

Then it gets weird - if I have a copy of the `./PFF/PFF` directory named `./PFF/PF` or `./PFF/P`, the `ERROR:` lines in both copies of the `.log` file are found (one in each of the directories;) if the duplicate directory is named with three or more characters (e.g. `./PFF/PFM`) the original `./PFF/PFF` log file is not found (or grepped; not sure yet which.)

It might be worth mentioning that the `./PFF` directory does have two other subdirs in addition to `./PFF/PFF` (`./PFF/PFF_FILE_HANDLING` and `./PFF/PFF_CAPTURE_FF`) so it doesn't appear that the problem is that `./PFF/PFF` is all alone.

```
find . -type f -name '*-2017-12-12_09.22.57.log' -exec grep -nHE 'ERROR:' {} \;
```

at the command line works as expected.

Now, I'm leery of `find-grep` (one of my go-to tools.)

Comment: Does `find-grep-dired` in Dired do a better job wrt your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately find-grep-dired finds ERROR: in many files that are uninteresting and takes much longer to run. (There are several thousand "uninteresting" files, each of which gets grepped.)

Curiously, `find-grep-dired` also failed to find any hits in `./PFF/PFF`

Comment: that exact command executed in a bash shell does find the missing file (which is actually how I found it existed; I was gobsmacked!)

Comment: *"`find...` at the command line works as expected."* -- then it sounds like an Emacs bug. `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: After 30+ years of Emacsing without problems, I'm not sure I'm comfortable filing a bug report until I've exhausted all possibilities. But you are probably right. Now, if only I could reproduce it with a smaller set of directories/files that are not proprietary. Thanks.

Comment: Bug report submitted.

Comment: Bug report/thread: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-12/msg00437.html